# Determine the response rate by age group

Tags: r, dplyr

In my data set (say dat1) I have a categorical variable called Campaign_Response which contain values False and True. Also in the same data set, I have created buckets for Age variable. This age_bucket variable has values like Teen, Adult and Senior. **Now I want to compute the campaign response rate by Age_bucket variable**. I started approaching this problem by using dplyr function where i did this:

```
dat1%>%group_by(Age_bucket)%>%summarize(ResponseRate= ???)
```

I am kind of stuck in the summarize part because Campaign_response is a categorical variable and I don't know how to proceed with this.
Could you please help me find out the response rate for the campaign by age bucket. Appreciate all your help. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please specify what format the output should have?

Comment: I want the response rate of campaign to be in form of percentage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or if you want to have the steps in between to check you can do something like this.

```
#some data made
Campaign_Resp <- c(T, F, T, T, F, T, F, T,F, T, T, F, T, F)
dat1 <- as.data.frame(Campaign_Resp)
Age <- c("Teen", "Teen", "Adult","Teen", "Adult","Adult", "Senior", "Teen", "Adult", "Adult", "Senior", "Adult", "Senior", "Senior")
dat1$Age <- Age

#transforming datatype
dat1$Campaign_Resp <- as.numeric(dat1$Campaign_Resp)

#using dplyr to count how many times a person inside a agegroup awnsered or not
dat2<- dat1%>%group_by(Age, Campaign_Resp) %>% summarise(Aantal= n())
dat3<- dat2 %>% spread(Campaign_Resp,value = Aantal)

#calculate non-responsive and responsive percentage
dat3$TOT <- dat3$`0`+ dat3$`1`
dat3$resp <- dat3$`1`/ dat3$TOT
dat3$nonresp <- dat3$`0`/ dat3$TOT
```

Comment: if you want the percentage.  You shoul do the last 2 steps times 100 of course.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that Campaign_Response is a logical vector, then use

```
dat1 %>% group_by(Age_bucket) %>% summarize(ResponseRate = mean(Campaign_Response))
```

Comment: Thanks for your input but I don't want need the mean of campaign_response, I want to find the proportion of true and false in campaign_response by age_bucket variable. Hope you understand of what I am trying to say.

Comment: That's exactly what my code gives you - the proportion of TRUE responders by age_bucket.

Answer (score 0):

```
# data generation
exempleData <- data.frame(order = 1:100 ,age_group = sample(c("A1","A2","A3"),100 ,replace = T),Response = sample(c(T,F),100 ,replace = T))
#compute rates
library(plyr)
rate     <- ddply(exempleData, 
                      .(age_group),
                      summarise, 
                      yes_rate = length(Response[Response == T]) / length(Response),
                      .parallel = F )
# display rates
rate
```

Answer (score -1):

What about this:

```
df <- data.frame(Campaign_Response = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE), 
                 Age_Bucket = c("teen", "adult", "senior", "teen", "adult", "senior"))
df %>% 
   group_by(Age_Bucket, Campaign_Response) %>% 
   summarize(ResponseRate = n())
```

And if you wanted to find out how many TRUE values you have per age group, you could do this:

```
df %>% 
   group_by(Age_Bucket) %>% 
   summarize(ResponseRate= sum(Campaign_Response))
```